# How to Redirect from Http to Https in Intranet?

Tags: vb.net, http, https

I have a vb.net application running as intranet on Win Server 2003. So should I use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

What is the difference or why should I if the answer is HTTPS? Is there any code in VB to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?

Thanking you all in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between HTTP and HTTPS, are you really sure you know what the internet is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) to ensure reasonable protection from [eavesdroppers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eavesdropping) and [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks. HTTPS creates a secure channel over the network, provided that adequate cipher suites are used and that the server certificate is [verified and trusted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_third_party).

An intranet is obviously less exposed than the public internet, but you should still use HTTPS if you are transferring sensitive data (such as passwords) from the server to the browsers.

Assuming you are using IIS to serve your website, you may want to check the following articles for further reading:

- [Microsoft Support - How To Set Up an HTTPS Service in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)
- [Forcing HTTPS in IIS 6.0](http://blog.kyanmedia.com/archives/2007/6/28/forcing_https_in_iis_60/)
- [Configure SSL on Your Website with IIS](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_ssl_on_your_website_with_iis.htm)